# How come my program does not quit?

Tags: python, function, exit, quit

Alright, so I've tried this for a while now and I can't seem to find a way to close the program once it is running.

What I want it to do is to end the program if the user chooses `'no'`:

```
elif y == 'n' or 'no':
    sys.exit(0)
```

However whatever I choose returns the program to the `partOne` function. I've tried different things to try and solve this, such as moving

```
partOne()
```

from the end of the program to in between the two functions but that does not work because then the `PartTwo` function has yet to be defined.

Thanks for your response.

```
import hashlib
import sys

def partOne():
    x = input("\nEnter something to hash: ")
    hash_object = hashlib.sha256(x.encode())
    hex_dig = hash_object.hexdigest()
    print("\nPlain text: ")
    print(x)
    print("\nHashed text: ")
    print(hex_dig)
    print("\nYour password: ")
    print(hex_dig[::9])
    partTwo()

def partTwo():
    y = input("\nDo you want to make another password? (y/n): ")
    if y == 'y' or 'yes':
        partOne()
    elif y == 'n' or 'no':
        sys.exit(0)
    else:
        print("\nYou need to type either 'y' or 'n'.")
        partOne()

partOne()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `y == 'n' or y =='no'`

instead of `y == 'n' or 'no'`

```
>>> y = 'anything'
>>> 
>>> bool(y == 'n' or 'no')
True
```

your statement always returns `True`. Instead of checking `y == 'no'` it just checks `'no'`, anything converted to bool in python is `True` if its not `None`, `False`, or `0`.

In case of strings and other iterables it returns True if its not empty, e.g. `''`, `[]`, `{}`, `()` will always return `False`.

Or as Foo Bar User says, `if y.lower() in ('n', 'no')` will also do. `lower()` will make sure that the matching is case insensitive.

Comment: or this  `y in ("yes","y")`